# Unique Index when data already exists

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, migration, unique

I ran into troubles when I want to add new column mapped ONE TO ONE. It creates unique index on that column and while executing SQL it obviously fail, because that table already contains rows. It's not a problem to remove data in development database, but it will be in a production db.

This is how the SQL looks like:

```
  $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE program_settings (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, booking_cancel VARCHAR(155) NOT NULL, booking_ahead VARCHAR(155) NOT NULL, created_at DATETIME NOT NULL, modified_at DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE program ADD settings_id INT NOT NULL AFTER studio_id');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE program ADD CONSTRAINT FK_92ED778459949888 FOREIGN KEY (settings_id) REFERENCES program_settings (id)');
    $this->addSql('CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_92ED778459949888 ON program (settings_id)');
```

What should I do in that case?

Comment: What is your SF2 or Mysql error ? I think the problem could be from your NOT NULL constraint on the settings_id column. You might want to remove this constraint, update your database field, and then put your NOT NULL constraint.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to put what was the error message, here you have:

Migration 20150301104253 failed during Execution. Error An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE program ADD CONSTRAINT FK_92ED778459949888 FOREIGN KEY (settings_id) REFERENCES program_settings (id)':

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`lightenbody_dev`.`#sql-580_4443`, CONSTRAINT `FK_92ED778459949888` FOREIGN KEY (`settings_id`) REFERENCES `program_settings` (`id`))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem could be from your NOT NULL constraint on the settings_id column.

You have to:

1. Add you foreign key (settings_id) without the NOT NULL constraint
2. Update all your foreign fields (settings_id) with values
3. ALTER your foreign key (settings_id) with NOT NULL constraint